# Questionable log message from OpenGL on Android

Tags: android, opengl-es, render, android-logcat

I've recently started debugging an OpenGL-based app on Android 3.2.  Each time I call requestRender() on my GLSurfaceView I get the following in LogCat:

12-13 07:22:20.380: I/GLThread(24032): waiting tid=11 mHaveEglContext: true mHaveEglSurface: true mPaused: false mHasSurface: true mWaitingForSurface: false mWidth: 1280 mHeight: 683 mRequestRender: false mRenderMode: 0

This didn't happen on 2.3 devices.

This is just an informational message, but is clogs up the log file and surely has some effect on performance when trying to draw at high frame rates.

The renderMode on the GLSurfaceView is RENDERMODE_WHEN_DIRTY so I need to explicitly call requestRender when I want the surface redrawn.

Any thoughts on the message and how to get rid of it?